# Need to identify first character of my string (variable)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a string called Policynumber

I need to know if it begins with a 1 or a 2 so I can create an if statement for if it starts with 1 do something and if it starts with 2 to do something else.

I keep finding ways to do this for string text but not for a variable.

I have tried doing the following:

```
If policynumber Like "1*" Then
    display.text = policynumber
End If
```

I am simply looking for possible ways to know what the first character is and therefore determine if it's a 1 or a 2.  When I try using the variable name or even a textbox.text I get no result in the display textbox so I know it's not working.

Comment: *I keep finding ways to do this for string text but not for a variable* - have you, uh, tried to see what you get by putting the variable in place of the string text? If your code isn't working, you need to [edit] your post to include a [mcve] if you want anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: @Mat'sMug possibly `newString =left(cell,1)`

Comment: @Splinxyy possibly many, many, many things, all of which involving the `VBA.Strings.Left` function or its string-typed `Left$` equivalent, yes. OP's question is unanswerable as it stands nonetheless.

Comment: @Splinxyy thank you for you concise and helpful answer   it worked.  clearly my question was answerable.  I thank you for not leaving unhelpful comments with your answer. I am new to vba and new to the boards.

Comment: To be honest mate, I've never even used VBA. I just googled it and it was the first thing that came up.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, posting on this site without a **specific** problem and a **[mcve]** is how you collect downvotes and close votes, and soon get banned from asking. Please read & understand [ask] - this "unhelpful" commenter is trying to help you 1) ask well-formed questions that will be favorably received, and 2) avoid an automatic question-ban by giving you links to [help/on-topic] resources. Thanks for editing your question into shape, have a great day.

Answer (score -2):

I would use VBA's ASC() function for this purpose. This function returns the ASCII code of the first character of a string. ASCII for the character 1 is 49 and 2 is 50. Therefore ...

```
Dim PolicyNumber As String
Dim n As Integer

PolicNumber = "1ABC-45678910"
n = ASC(PolicyNumber)
MsgBox "Policy number starts with a " & Chr(n)
```

For testing the result you can use either `If n = 49 Then` or `If Chr(n) = "1" Then`.

Comment: Feels like a hack though, `Left$(PolicyNumber, 1)` says what it does, and does what it says. If the hack is for performance, then using `Chr$` to avoid the implicit `Variant` to `String` conversion would probably benchmark better.

Comment: @Mat's Mug A surprising comment from a high-rated expert. You are airing unfounded prejudices. What, in your valued opinion, is the ASC() function for if it isn't for cases like this one?

Comment: `Asc` clearly means to work off a single character; the truncation of the input being essentially a side-effect of that - an alternative implementation could just as well have thrown an error given a string of greater length; fortunately the designers decided to just work off the first character given, and ignore the rest of the string, so `Chr(Asc("foo"))` works and returns the `f`... just as `Left("foo", 1)` would, in a much clearer way that uses standard library functions the way they were intended to be used, not for their side-effects. Why use hacks when the proper functions are there?

Comment: That said "side-effects" isn't really the wording I'm trying to convey, hopefully it doesn't distract from the actual point.

Comment: @Mat's Mug You haven't really made a point other than that you consider the ASC() function a hack per se. Can you substantiate your contention that ASC() might throw an error given a string of greater length? I think it was designed to work on streams, implying strings of very great length. `Chr(Asc("foo")` isn't required in this case. Therefore `Asc("foo")` is both shorter and faster than `Left("foo", 1)`, meaning more efficient. The rest is a matter of what you are used to seeing - a matter of very personal preference impossible to argue for or against.

Comment: I never said `Asc` is a hack in itself, nor that it *does* throw an error, you're twisting my words now, so this discussion is ending now. `Asc` is documented to work the way it does, so fine, use it that way. Have a nice day.

Comment: Downvoted because the code does more than really necessary. We're converting it to an ASCII value, only to convert it back to a one-character string. This also harms the code's readability because I have to wonder why we needed the ASCII value. Heck, I would wonder why I need to know 49 is ASCII's "1". `Left$(x, 1)` gives the same result without introducing ASCII values in the process.

Comment: You need to *know* that `Asc` only operates on the first character, otherwise it's not obvious what `Asc` is doing. Both `Left` and `Mid` would more clearly express your intention. `Asc` also needs a guard clause for a zero-length string, as `Asc("")` will error with *Runtime Error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument.*, where `Left` and `Mid` will not. `Asc` will also *only* work reliably on Macs up to character code 127, and for Unicode support on Windows, you'd need to use `AscW` which then requires checking more than one byte.

Comment: Of course, for Ascii characters, you could just declare `PolicyNumber() As Byte`, and check `PolicyNumber(0)`, but you could also use `CopyMemory` with `StrPtr`....But none of these solutions clearly express what you're trying to do, and should only be used if performance is provably better, and the input domain is properly handled.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Thank you for your constructive intervention. The task at hand is to examine the first character of a policy number and take different action depending upon whether it is "1" or "2". It won't be a Chinese character but it might be something else, incl a null string. For such eventualities the code would need to provide in any case. `Left(String, 1)` seems to have a very strong following here. I use the ASC() function all the time. Therefore I know that it examines the first character.  I feel relieved that there is no technical argument against it.